# Django: how to write code for modelform of user registration

Tags: django, validation, registration, modelform

I would want to make register form and check if the
user's email is a new one by checking the DB.

But the problem is that I don't know how to make it. 
I tried using unique=True to Field and clean_email() method.

I have 2 questions.

1) When ValidationError happens at the step of unique=True,
how could I catch that error? should I override the clean_field() method
of Model? And How could I make it?

2) how could I write efficient and nice code for this registration app?

Below are the source code i made.

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    university = models.ForeignKey('University')
    mail = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField()
    nickname = models.CharField()


class University(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    mail = models.CharField()


from django.forms import ModelForm

class LoginForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('mail', 'password')

class RegisterForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    def clean_mail(): 
        data = self.cleaned_data['mail']
        if User.objects.filter(mail=data).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("This email is already exists")

# views.py

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ###
        if form.is_valid():
```

I am so confused to make this. 
I am waiting for a help Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't catch that error. Django does it for you: when you call `form.is_valid()`, it calls each of the clean_field methods and catches any ValidationError exceptions, putting them into the form.errors attribute.

So, what you have is already fine.

Except for the major, huge, absolutely vital issue that **you should never store passwords in plain text**. Don't create your own standalone user class: inherit from AbstractBaseUser and use Django's built-in methods to create users and hash their passwords. You must not do it like this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how can i get information bout AbstractBaseUser and Django's built-in methods for that?

Comment: Why not try looking in [the comprehensive documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)?

Comment: Can I ask one more? But how can I configure the error message which appear when unique=True of database triggers validationerror? I could not find it in the django 1.5 manual ...

Answer (score 1):

First of All, Your **clean_mail() should return self.cleaned_data['mail']** , if error is not raised. Although clean_mail is not required here

Secondly, Django **will automatically check for uniqueness of the Email** if you set unique=Ture in Model. An error would be raised if it is not unique. 
You can over-ride unique error text by providing that in ModelForm's Meta options.

e.g.

```
class RegisterForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        error_messages = {
            'mail': {
                'unique': _("This email already exists"),
            },
        }
```

Note: error_messages option has been added in django v1.6 only...
For previous versions:

You can over-ride the field mail in the ModelForm directly. e.g Define at top of the ModelForm

```
class RegisterForm(ModelForm):
    mail = forms.EmailField(max_length=255, error_messages = { 'unique': 'xyz....',})
    class Meta:.......
```

you can find reference here:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/fields/#error-messages

Comment: Where can I find the reference about error_messages of Meta option of ModelForm? I could not find it in django 1.5 manual..

Comment: error_messages option has been added in version 1.6, for that you can find it here :https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields..

Comment: But for version 1.5 you can over-ride the field mail in the ModelForm directly. e.g Define at top of the ModelForm
mail = forms.EmailField(max_length=255, error_messages = { 'unique': 'xyz....',})

you can find reference here:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/fields/#error-messages

Answer (score 0):

Take a quick look at the following page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/

The section "Validating objects" guides you through the steps in model validation.

If you require single-column uniqueness on `User.mail`, simply add the keyword `unique=True` to the `Charfield`. The stock implementation of `validate_unique()` will handle this.

Comment: This is a question about form validation, not model validation.